# setting the public path not working with AOT compiling

Tags: webpack

I'm working on an angular app with aot compiling. All our resources will be loaded through a CDN so I set my public path to that CDN's URL. Everything is looking okay except for the chunks. All the chunks are still being loaded from the base href.

I've tried setting the publicPath in the output property of my webpack config as well as setting `__webpack_public_path__` in my entry file and nothing works with aot compilation.

Everything works as expected with jit mode.